# How can I modify the appearance of 'empty' cells in plain UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

If you have a plain (not grouped) UITableView with a single row, the rest of the screen is filled with blank or empty cells. How do you change the appearance of these blank cells? Af first, I thought they would have the appearance of the cell used in the table view but it seems they don't.

The people from Cultured Code (Things) have done a nice job modifying these cells but I can't immediately think of a way to change their appearance.

Any tips?

Comment: *Bump* got a solution that works? Please share here. Thanks

Comment: What I've done so far is add an 'invisible' cell at the end of the table view with an imageview that displays the shadow of the end of the table view. I have set the separator style to none. This creates a similar effect but I'll have to tweak it a bit more to be happy with it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although it's not quite what you're looking for, you can also change it to just display a blank region (instead of blank cells) by setting a footer view on the table.  A UIView of height 0 will do the trick.

Comment: With your help, I figured it out and it is quite simple. Add the desired UIImageView to the footer of the UITableView (as you suggested) but to have the table view behave correctly you have to increase its height with the height of the UIImageView. This way, the table view will behave as a normal table view but you have the nice effect I was looking for. Be sure to remove the cell separators of the table view.

Comment: Do you have any code for this that works? I'm having trouble reproducing what's explained here

Comment: Here's what worked for me. In iOS 6.1, it doesn't seem like I have to increase the height of the view: myTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];

Comment: iOS 7/8 now and I can't figure out how zero height view works. It just doesn't show up for me. UPDATE: Well actually it does work. If you add the zero height view the table view will not render empty cell, just white space. What I need is to put something into this view. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [samvermette's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87158/samvermette) answer, but modified to use a background image directly rather than compositing an image from a UITableViewCell subclass. Sam's answer is good, but it will be less performant than just creating a background image directly.

Create a UIView subclass -- in this example I called it CustomTiledView -- and add the following code to the class:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview_empty_cell_image"];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextScaleCTM (context, 1, -1); 
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, 
                        CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, image.size.height), 
                        [image CGImage]); 
}
```

Add the following code to your tableviewcontroller:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // this can be any size, but it should be 1) multiple of the 
    // background image height so the last empty cell drawn
    // is not cut off, 2) tall enough that footer cells
    // cover the entire tableview height when the tableview
    // is empty, 3) tall enough that pulling up on an empty
    // tableview does not reveal the background.
        return BACKGROUND_IMAGE_HEIGHT * 9; // create 9 empty cells
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CustomTiledView *footerView = [[CustomTiledView alloc] init];
    return [footerView autorelease];
}
```

Finally, you'll need to set the bottom content inset of your tableview to the negative of the value returned from `-tableView:heightForFooterInsection:` In this example it would be `-1*BACKGROUND_IMAGE_HEIGHT*9`. You can set the bottom content inset either from the Size Inspector of Interface Builder or by setting the `self.tableView.contentInset` property from the tableviewcontroller.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I set a ~300px-high UIView subclass to my tableView header and footer views, adjusting the tableView insets so they compensate for these views (set the top and bottom insets to -300px).

My UIView subclass implements the drawRect method, in which I use `CGContextDrawTiledImage()` to draw an empty `UITableViewCell` repetitively:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(300, 46),NO,0.0);
    emptyCell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [emptyCell drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 46)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [emptyCell release];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, 1, -1); // this prevents the image from getting drawn upside-down
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 46), [newImage CGImage]);
}
```

In my case my tableviewcells are 46px high, so if I want make UIView subclass to contain 8 of these empty cells, I need to make it 368px high.

Comment: I like this solution, but it could use some tweaks. For one, I think allocating a tableviewcell just to draw it is rather heavy-handed. The idea behind it is pretty genius -- the empty cells will automagically reflect any changes you make to the custom tableviewcell design. I'd have to imagine though that the design would not change very often, so there probably isn't a good use case to use this generic approach. Rather, I would just create an image from what the cell looks like and use that.

Comment: Also, I'm not a fan of magic numbers in code. I see why you are forced to use them here -- you need to know the context frame _before_ you load the empty cell -- but really you should be drawing to the rect size you are given.

Comment: With the above in mind, I added an answer based on your code, but which grabs the background image directly rather than using an actual tableViewCell. However, I gave this answer +1 as well since I think it is an interesting and viable approach.

Answer (score 3):

From http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/03/hide-uitableview-empty-cell-separator.html
Easy way is to define that table has no cell separator lines:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Hard way, if you need separator lines, is to define that table has no separator lines and create cell separator lines as part of custom UITableViewCell. Bottom part of cell, obviously, and most likely using really thin graphics image. Remember to define image autosizing and mode properly.

Another way is to define an empty UITableView's tableFooterView:

```
UIView *footer =
    [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.myTable.tableFooterView = footer;
[footer release];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to change the height of the "empty cells" when there are no cells at all in your TableView: you need to set the `rowHeight` property of your UITableView (the implementation of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` has no effect on empty TableViews). If there are cells in your TableView and you have implemented `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` then the last row height will be used for empty cells.

Comment: This will change the height of all cells, regardless of what `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` does.

Comment: @executor21: not true, `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` always overrides the value you set via the `rowHeight` property, but it will only be applied if there is at least one cell.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to make a custom subclass of UITableView that fills the background with the appearance of blank cells.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [super drawRect: rect];

  // draw your background here if the rect intersects with the background area
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the approach of using the `UITableView` `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` method will not work for the case where the table is empty, ie., with no cells. In that case, you can use the technique [Answerbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257550/answerbot) proposed can be repurposed to stuff the created `UIView` into the table's footer view explicitly, like the following:

```
    CGRect cellRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, table.bounds.size.width, table.bounds.size.height);
    CustomTiledView *footerView = [[[CustomTiledView alloc] initWithFrame:cellRect] autorelease];
    table.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift **4.0** :

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```