# How to set the default UITableViewCell height?

Tags: uitableview

I am using variable heights for my UITableViewCells. This works fine normally however
I am finding that whatever the very last cell's height is, that becomes the height for all of the blank cells below it.

Is there a way to set a default height for the blank cells that appear below the last cell?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022637/modify-appearance-of-empty-cells-is-plain-uitableview), it might help. Do not miss the comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using switch statement then set the default height for empty cells in default case of switch. Like so

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int rowHeight = 40;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            rowHeight = 80;
            break;
        case 1:
            rowHeight = 300;
            break;
        default:
            rowHeight = <your default value>;
            break;
    }

    return rowHeight;
}
```