# UITableView - Lines Between Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that has cells of which, for this example, let's say only the top two are filled. For the rest of the cells going down the list there are still separator lines.

Is there a way to turn the lines off where there are empty cells but keep them on to separate cells that contain information?

Comment: Look at this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022637/how-can-i-modify-the-appearance-of-empty-cells-in-plain-uitableview

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No there is no built in support for this.

You could turn off the cells on the table view with:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

And then draw the separator lines in your own `UITableViewCell` subclasses that you use for the rows.

Comment: How would I draw my own separator lines?

Comment: @James - I would go for a 1 point high `UIView` instance that you set the background color on.

Comment: Does this answer really need to be changed to Swift? The question is tagged Objective-C for heavens sake! I rolled it back to the initial version for Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

Another simple hack is to add this to the UITableViewControllers viewDidLoad Method:

```
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way is do just write the line in **viewdidLoad**

```
self.myTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the above (@Ekkstein's) answer.