# Why does last cell's height of UITableView get used for remaining empty cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My cells all have varying heights, determined by text entered by the user.

Whatever height the last cell takes on seems to determine (change) the height for all remaining blank cells.

It doesn't appear that heightForRowAtIndexPath is getting called for these remaining, empty cells, nor is CFRAIP.

Does anyone know how to fix this or why it is happening?

Comment: That is odd: you should get as many calls to HFRAIP/CFRAIP as the number of visible cells, blank or not. Is this not what you see?

Comment: No, just calls for cells I actually need. Empties it's reusing dimensions from last used cell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this code in viewDidLoad of the the viewController where Tableview is placed.

`self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];`

Comment: Great one! but do rectify it.. it should be self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

I meet the problem too. And it frustrated me much. After some consideration, I think it may be a feature of tableview that it show blank cell. It's reasonable to use the last cell height for the blank cell. Otherwise, what height to choose to use?
I think it's not acceptable to show black cell. If you dislike the style like me, you can try this to get rid of blank cells:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

or

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
//then add view for separator line by yourself
```

or

```
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableView.backgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor;
self.tableView = tableView;
```

If you must show blank cell and control the height, maybe it's the simplest way/workaround to add additional cell. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return self.dataArray == nil || self.dataArray.count == 0 ? 1 : self.dataArray + 1;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.count == self.dataArray.count){ //the last cell
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    } else {
       cell = .... //as uausal
    }

    return cell;
   }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.count == self.dataArray.count){
      return 50;
   } else {
    return xxx; //as usual
   }
 }
```

Now we can control any height !.

Hope it can help you.

You can refer to the link as well: [How can I modify the appearance of 'empty' cells in plain UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022637/how-can-i-modify-the-appearance-of-empty-cells-in-plain-uitableview)