# Adjusting TabelView's cell height affects trailing empty cells when cell is last

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am currently using the following tableView delegate method to adjust the height of individual cells when they are selected:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = 44.0f;
    if (self.selectedIndexPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedIndexPath.row){
        return height + 20;
    }
    return height;
}
```

This function works fine when the cell adjusted is not the last cell to be shown.  However, if its the **last cell**, the function adversely affects the height of **all** the trailing empty cells as well, as shown in the illustration:

Not last cell (user "bansvsiena" selected)

[image]

Last cell ("newregistant" selected - notice all the trailing cells also have the same height)

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: I tend to run into this issue a lot when making table cells of varying heights. The fix outlined in the question will help and it'll also get rid of the empty trailing cells.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294636/why-does-last-cells-height-of-uitableview-get-used-for-remaining-empty-cells

Comment: Just a comment, would you like to hide the separators at the bottom? This would solve your problem.

Comment: Hiding the separators would be fine here and it did work! Thanks for suggesting this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for you:

1. Why don't you remove separator from all your empty cells? You can set yout `UITableView's` separator style to `single line etched`. Doing this will not show separators for your empty cells.
2. After setting `self.selectedIndexPath` value (I suppose you did it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`) you are reloading your table. You can void doing this and just do following

   `[_tblCredits reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath,  self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

As your all the cells will be created with 44px height at first and you won't be reloading the table so height will change only for those rows which you pass in array. This approach is much better to reload only those rows which need to reload instead of whole table.

Hope this helps :)