# UITableView empty cells dont use background color of filled cells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, background-color

How can I make the cells that are empty below have the same background color with opacity as my first item in the table?  I also want to keep my rounded corners but having issues getting a background color on those empty cells while keeping the table opaque to see the background.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.itemsTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableCell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIView* myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    myBackgroundView.opaque = NO;
    myBackgroundView.alpha = 0.7;

    tableCell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
    tableCell.opaque = NO;
    tableCell.alpha = 0.7;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Those aren't empty cells, those are just separators that show up by default. Sounds like what you really want to do is resize your table view to fit the cells you have.

Comment: Try setting the footer view to an empty view.

Comment: What will setting the footer view do?

Comment: It will remove the extra decorative separators below your cells.

Comment: But I want them there?  I want the cell background to be the same as the first, not sure you understand my question.

Comment: Your question is vague. Your screenshot only shows one cell. You seem to be confusing decorative separators for actual cells.

Comment: Try setting the background color of the table view _instead_ of the background color of the cells.

Comment: I am, I want those "decorative" cells to have that brown background.

Comment: You are setting the background view of the cells instead of the table.

Comment: Yep, I did this because of issues with rounded corners and opacity.  I can try again.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022637/how-can-i-modify-the-appearance-of-empty-cells-in-plain-uitableview)